# False Dudeney : triangle to quiet a square.

Tags: geometry

ABC is an equilateral triangle.
The same color polygons are isometric.

I can prove that MPQR is a rectangle, but not that it's not a square.

MI = IP and  RF' = F'Q = FN.

As MPQR is a rectangle MI = IP = RF' = F'Q = FN.

This equalities are independent of the choice of E and F.

PQ = QR is equivalent to : EM + EN = 2FN

Why in this case : PQ is not equal to RQ ?

[image]

Comment: You could say at least that forms with the same color are isometric. What are the other assumptions : are angles in M and N assumed to be right angles ? Moeover, your title is not understandable. By lack of information, I suggest to close this very ambiguous question.

Comment: Ok close it please. I will improve it tomorrow. Sorry.

Comment: Btw M and N are right angles by computation.

Comment: I just understood your title now ; you should have given a reference such as (http://bestforpuzzles.com/bits/canterbury-puzzles/index.html) see : 26.—The Haberdasher's Puzzle.

Comment: You need to show that ME=NJ which implies PQ=RQ. This depends on on the choice of I and J,

Comment: @JeanMarie: Well, [Dudeney's dissection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hinged_dissection) is well known in recreational geometry. However, I don't understand the phrase "triangle to quiet a square" either.

Comment: It's not a real Dudeney puzzle. The result is a rectangle that looks like a square. The goal is to prove that it is not a square. It's French college level proof but I miss something.

Comment: Thank you @Rahul for the reference you gave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution to this problem.

[image]